# How to test Google Analytics in firefox browser?

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console, firefox, event-tracking, universal-analytics

As a part of Google analytics testing i need to check the events triggered, hit types, conversions, custom dimensions etc..

So i need to check the above mentioned attributes in Firefox browser.
I couldnt find any good extensions in firefox browser that helps my testing as i found in google chrome.

Can any one let me know if there is any possibilty to test Google Analytics in firefox browser

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried WASP?

Comment: Hi Lucgenti,

I tried checking WASP add-on for firefox but no luck.

Comment: I think you should try again, because it's a very handy tool and is good in letting you know what analytics is doing.

Comment: Hi Lucgenti,I have tried checking the WASP addon for firefox. Few trails made me to learn that WASP addon is supported by only older versions of firefox. my testing carries on firefox 38 version. Can you please provide me any link that gives me info regarding google analytics testing in firefox.

Comment: Software recommendations are off-topic here. Anyway, I highly suggest to change browser when testing Google Analytics.

Comment: I just managed to check the google analytics parameters in firefox.
Hope this helps.
Open firefox browser->Tools->WebDeveloper-> webConsole
You would be prompted with a seperate or autofitted window.
Then go to Tool Box options-> Enable google Chrome addon debugging in advanced settings.
Then check in the network tab. you would get all the query parameters as you see in google.

Comment: If that's ok for you, answer your question by yourself and approve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just managed to check the google analytics parameters in firefox. Hope this helps. Open firefox browser->Tools->WebDeveloper-> webConsole You would be prompted with a seperate or autofitted window. Then go to Tool Box options-> Enable google Chrome addon debugging in advanced settings. Then check in the network tab. you would get all the query parameters as you see in google.

Also switch on the GTM debugger in firefox to check the query parameters more reasonable